# MODx :: Get Session ID set by MODx to use in Module

Tags: php, content-management-system, modx, modx-evolution

I have an issue where I need to pass the Session ID to a module, "SMF Connector".

The problem stems from the fact that for some reason the SMF Forum (held in a sub-folder) is using a different Session set. I combatted the problem by hard coding the Session ID from MODx, but of course this then failed the next time I loaded up the site a day later.

I have tried using

```
global $modx;  
$SID = $modx->documentObject[SID];
session_id($SID);
session_start();
```

But to no avail, infact it was stopping the entire forum from loading!

Any ideas?

Comment: Please make sure error reporting and display errors are set to high enough levels. It sounds like an error is occurring, and it would be helpful to know the error to diagnose the issue.

Comment: I enabled full error_reporting() but it doesnt even get that far. By eliminating each line, I found out its the $SID = $modx->documentObject[SID]; that is causing the page to break. I get a "Content Encoding Error - The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression." page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that modx session data is limited to index.php and scripts included from there. I suppose this is by design.

From what I gather, your SMF script is invoked by a seperate request. Try adding the following lines at the start of your external php script:

```
// start MODx session to access its session data
require_once ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/manager/includes/config.inc.php');
startCMSSession();
```