# How to set cookies when using modx?

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies, modx

I am trying to set a cookie with the following code from an external script but for some reason When I try to read the cookie from Javascript or php it never shows the information that I inserted, it only shows the Modx cookie information. What am I missing?

```
$modx = new modX();
$modx->initialize('web');

$_SESSION["username"] = $_POST["username"];
$_SESSION["member_num"] =  $result["member_num"];
setcookie("member_num", $result["member_num"], time()+3600);
```

Comment: Possible similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044326/modx-get-session-id-set-by-modx-to-use-in-module

Answer (score 0):

You must start the session before setting any cookie.

```
require_once ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/manager/includes/config.inc.php');

startCMSSession();

$modx = new modX();
$modx->initialize('web');

$_SESSION["username"] = $_POST["username"];
$_SESSION["member_num"] =  $result["member_num"];
setcookie("member_num", $result["member_num"], time()+3600);
```